# In android phonegap how to place notification badge on app icon

Tags: android, cordova, notifications

I am developing my app using cordova(i.e phonegap) , am unable to place a badge on app icon which is used to represent count of notifications received.

Note: I got my sender id and api key by following the steps mentioned by google,and am receiving the notification pretty good .

Please help me by providing relevant code .

Thanks in advance.